# Unit testing a function that outputs via XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm trying to get into the unit testing and [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) way of doing things but I've come across a problem I'm not sure what to do with.

I have a collection that saves itself to disk using XDocument and XmlWriter.  I know you shouldn't write the file to disk then check it so I had the XmlWriter output to a memory stream then I checked the contents of the memory stream.  The function looks like this:

```
   public void Save()
    {
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(m_StreamProvider.SaveFileStream(m_FilenameProvider.Filename)))
        {
            XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("BookmarkCollection",
                    Items.Select(bookmark => new XElement("Bookmark",
                        new XElement("Name", bookmark.Name),
                        new XElement("Link", bookmark.Link),
                        new XElement("Remarks", bookmark.Remarks),
                        new XElement("DateAdded", bookmark.DateAdded),
                        new XElement("DateLastAccessed", bookmark.DateLastAccessed))
                        )
                        ));

            xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
        }

    }
```

And the unit test is

```
[Test]
    public void Save_OneItemCollection_XmlCreatedCorrectly()
    {
        //Arrange
        MemoryStreamProvider streamProvider = new MemoryStreamProvider();
        IBookmarkCollection collection = XBookmarkTestHelpers.GetXBookmarkCollection(streamProvider);

        IBookmark bookmarkToAdd = XBookmarkTestHelpers.GetIBookmark("myLink");
        collection.Add(bookmarkToAdd);

        //Act
        collection.Save();

        //Assert
        streamProvider.WriteStrean.Position = 0;
        String generatedXml = Encoding.Default.GetString(streamProvider.WriteStrean.GetBuffer());

        Assert.IsTrue(String.Equals(generatedXml, m_ExpectedOneItemString), "XML does not match");
    }
```

The assert here fails too fragile (I know I could use String.Compare() but it would have similar issues.),  Am I testing the right thing?  Am I mocking the wrong thing?

All input greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing that feels wrong about the Save function is that it actually has two responsibilities: it selects a storage and it serializes an object graph to this storage. I would start by isolating responsibilities:

```
public void Save(XmlWriter xmlWriter)
{
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("BookmarkCollection",
        Items.Select(bookmark => new XElement("Bookmark",
            new XElement("Name", bookmark.Name),
            new XElement("Link", bookmark.Link),
            new XElement("Remarks", bookmark.Remarks),
            new XElement("DateAdded", bookmark.DateAdded),
            new XElement("DateLastAccessed", bookmark.DateLastAccessed))
        )
    ));
    xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
}

public void Save()
{
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(m_StreamProvider.SaveFileStream(m_FilenameProvider.Filename)))
    {
        Save(xmlWriter);
    }
}
```

As far as the unit test is concerned, you could define an XSD schema and then [validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444064/easiest-way-to-validate-and-read-an-xml-file-in-net) the result XML against this schema and also test that it contains the values you are looking for.

Comment: +1 This very clearly expresses many of the things I could only hint at in my own answer and comments. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, I use [XNode.DeepEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx) to compare XML instances with each other because it compares structure, not bytes.

Comment: I was thinking about loading the string into an XDocument then comparing with a 'Blue Peter' style one I made earlier, but is that going to far?

Comment: You should only make assertions about the changes that you care about. Sometimes that would be the entire XML document, and sometimes it would be that a very specific elemet/attribute was added. In the latter case, I would query the resulting document with XLINQ to examine the node in question. I'm not, however, sure that this was exactly what you asked about...

Comment: OTOH, I definitely think you are on the right track when it comes to using an XmlWriter instead of hitting the disk, so I definitely appreciate the added flexibility. However, it seems to me that your API still has a 'file system smell' over it. Why not just operate directly on an XmlWriter and forget about the file system?

Comment: I haven't phrased it very but I was trying to see if I was doing right.  I think the querying it with XLINQ might be the way to go.