# Alternative to TidyCOM

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, tidy, xml-validation

My clients web application is using TidyCOM to clean up dynamically created XML files from a SQL database query. With this TidyCOM, they are not able to upgrade the web application to .Net 4.0 framework. Is there an alternative to using TidyCOM so that these dynamically created XML files are validated correctly?

Comment: Do you want to validate the output as XML or as HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [TidyCOM](http://ablavier.pagesperso-orange.fr/TidyCOM/) was a wrapper for [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), you could use ['A managed wrapper for the HTML Tidy library'](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ZetaHtmlTidy.aspx) on CodeProject or ['HTML Tidy wrapper for .NET'](http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931).

Comment: is there any other option to validate XML besides using Tidy whatsoever

Comment: Assuming a .Net solution and access to the schema, there are native .net implementations using XmlReader and XmlSchema. The answers to this question have good info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444064/easiest-way-to-validate-and-read-an-xml-file-in-net